# Spring Injecting Beans from src folder in test folders

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have utility classes exposed as beans in my source folders. I want to use some of those utilities in my test classes written in junit 4. For example , I have a utility class that has methods which marshal an object into JSON string. I want to inject this utility bean in my test class. I am unable to inject these beans using Autowired annotation. Should I copy all these classes over to test folder?

Edit:

I am trying to inject jsonUtil. Below is how my code looks like.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ProxyApplicationMock.class)
public class ProxyApplicationMock {

    @Mock
    public SoapClient soapClientMock;

    private JsonUtil jsonUtil;
```

Main Class

```
public class ProxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show example of your test class code with the Spring context configuration and tell us which version of Spring you are using.

Comment: Hi Matt , added the code and I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: Ok, have a look at my answer and let me know if it's any help. Showing your Spring config file would help too : `ProxyApplicationMock`

Comment: I don't have any spring config file. We are using java configuration.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I didn't see that the class provided in `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is the annotated class. That's not correct, you should provide a config class for your test and you should use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` as the runner instead of `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

Comment: Its a spring boot app and I don't have a single java config file. I have all the classes defined with @Component annotation.

Comment: Whether it's a Spring Boot app or not, in order to inject a Spring Bean, your test needs to be executed in a Spring context. Unless you use a `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` or the shorter alias `SpringRunner` and specify a context configuration (Java or xml, doesn't matter), there's no way for JUnit to know that you want to execute the test within a Spring context.

Comment: Apparently, with Spring Boot, you now have an annotation (`@SpringBootTest`) to avoid passing context configuration and to tell it to automatically find a `SpringBootConfiguration` annotated class

Answer (score 1):

Your main classes can be seen by your test classes, but not the other way around. So no, you don't need to copy them.

If your utility class is declared as a Spring managed bean in your test Spring context configuration (the class -or XML file- declared in the `@ContextConfiguration`) which may and probably should be different from your main configuration.

Then you can inject it in any Spring managed class, which includes your test classes if it's using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

EDIT:

To sum up what we discussed in the comments, the main problem is that your test runner is not a `SpringRunner` (alias for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`), and thus JUnit is not running your test in a Spring context. Have a look at [a test example here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/src/test/java/sample/data/jpa/service/CityRepositoryIntegrationTests.java).

The simplest test case will look like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest 
public class CityRepositoryIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MySpringBean springBean;
    //...
}
```

But as often with Spring Boot, there's some magic happening behind. [`@SpringBootTest`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.java) is a convenient annotation that will detect automatically a class annotated with `@SpringBootConfiguration`, meaning if you don't have a specific Spring configuration for your test, it will use your main Spring configuration, and thus include and instanciate all the beans for your main app, and that's not usually what we want in a unit test cause we want to test a class independently by mocking its dependencies.

What you can do, is provide the Spring compenent classes you want to include in your tests, as such:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringBean.class)
public class CityRepositoryIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MySpringBean springBean;

    @Mock
    private MyMockedSpringBeanDependency mocked;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am using Jackson , but have done a number of customization to the marshalling and unmarshalling sections in my util

Answer (score 0):

This question is to Matt, since adding comment is throwing error saying only one additional use can be notified.

NOTE: Not an Answer

I have an Application class & many config classes which are imported in Application class. Earlier it was @Configuration, which I converted to @SpringBootConfiguration in Application class and the actual Config class, whos bean I am trying to mock. Ended up in

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.getSpringApplication(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:84)
```

Please suggest How do I mock, I have the same setup as specified in the ticket.

```
@Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager()
    {
            EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
            factoryBean.setShared(true);
            return new EhCacheCacheManager(factoryBean.getObject());
        }
    }
```